# Thinktecture IdentityServer v3 OIDC IE Issue

Tags: internet-explorer, single-sign-on, thinktecture-ident-server

I have setup Thinktecture IdentityServer v3 (great product).  The single sign-on is working great for all browsers.  The issue I am running into is with the single sign-out.  I am using the standard OIDC.js setup from the samples.  This works great for Chrome and FF, but for IE the user gets automatically logged out.  Any time the script checks the session state, it is always returned as "changed".  Has anyone else ran into this issue and been able to resolve it?

Comment: Is particular version of IE you are running on?

Comment: This is happening in the IE 11.  When I change it to another version of IE, it just throws a CORS error.  Not sure what the issue is, as it is working just fine in other browsers.